# Format "data" and "name" highchart mvc asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts, format

I'm in a MVC application, and I'm having problems to generate a chart in highchart, I have this code

```
                   foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    object[] values = new object[3];
                    values[0] = i;
                    values[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ini) ;
                    values[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ir);

                    dataResult.Add(values);
                }
```

generates the following:

[image]

passed to the json which returns me this chart

[image]

What I like is that the value of "IRI201308NF3" was the name of the series and the other two values ​​gerarariam the correct chart.

Under the Json

```
 $.getJSON("/GrafLev/GetDadosByGraficos", { parameter },
                function (data) {
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            ignoreHiddenSeries: false
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Exchange rate'
                            },
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: limInferior,
                                color: 'green',
                                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                                width: 2,
                                label: {
                                    text: 'Inferior'
                                }
                            }, {
                                value: limSuperior,
                                color: 'red',
                                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                                width: 2,
                                label: {
                                    text: 'Superior'
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                        },
                        series: [{ data: data }]
                    });
            });
```

I found this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sujay/UMeGS/), but I can not format.
The only thing is that the graph is a line.

Comment: Please show us the javascript code where you call `Highcharts` with JSON dataResult.

Comment: I'am edit the question and put the end.

Comment: As I understand I have to format before generating the graph, but I'm on time and I'm not getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the `Highcharts` [api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data), it's series parameter is looking for an array of dictionaries with a `name` and `data` property.  You are passing the `data` property a mixed array.  Now, you could reformat the response JSON in the javascript, but I think it's cleaner to format the JSON properly in the `C#`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dataResult = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataResult["data"] = new List<object[]>();
dataResult["name"] = i;
foreach (var item in query)
{
    object[] values = new object[2];
    values[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ini) ;
    values[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(item.ir);
    ((List<object[]>)dataResult["data"]).Add(values);
}
```

This will result in JSON looking like this:

```
{"data":[[0,0],[1,10],[2,20],[3,30],[4,40],[5,50],[6,60],[7,70],[8,80],[9,90]],"name":"Hi Mom"}
```

Now you should be good to pass this to the series parameter as:

```
series: [ data ]
```

Note, this JSON is still returning a single series.  If you need to return multiple series, just comment and I'll modify the code.

**EDITS**

For multiple series add an outer list containing each series `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Here's an example:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> dataResult = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>();
    aSeries["name"] = "Series " + i.ToString();

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        object[] values = new object[2];
        values[0] = j;
        values[1] = j * 10 * i;
        ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values);
    }

    dataResult.Add(aSeries);
}
```

Pass to `Highcharts` as:

```
series: data
```

Comment: I need several series, could modify the code please